Container scrolling to top when hitting enter on suneditor-react input on keyboard for new line
I am using suneditor-react npm package in a nextjs application. The container where i am using it is scrollable. It's working fine but when i hit enter after finishing a line for new line, the container is scrolling automatically to top position.
The editor is not loosing focus but it's getting out of view when the container scroller is in it's top position. Looking for a solution.
I have tried to solve it by providing onKeyDown callback and intercepting the keyboard enter event but it's still not working.

Having same issue. you find any solution ?

No, i just moved to another text editor, we can intercept the enter event to re adjust the scroll position, but that's giving a flicker issue on the ui.

Same issue here. Replacing SunEditor will be a big lift but looks like it will need to be done sooner than later.
